# Constructor of Dbcontext keeps changing the base argument on update of model

Tags: c#, visual-studio, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

In my context class I have the following to make the project a black box for data.

```
     public MyEntities()
        : base("metadata = res://*/fda.csdl|res://*/fda.ssdl|res://*/fda.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string='data source=MyServer;initial catalog=CitywideEmployees;persist security info=True;user id=MyUserID;password=MyPassword!;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework'")
    {
    }
```

However when I update the edmx, using the "Update Model from Database" option, it always resets the base argument, almost like it wants to look in an App.config file for the connection string. How do I prevent having to update the base every time I update the edmx?

Thanks.

Comment: What if  you deploy your application? You force all deployment sites to have the same server and database names.

Comment: Yeah that's fine, it's a black box - that's the intention.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open your {your name}.Context.tt and save the following change

```
<#=Accessibility.ForType(container)#> partial class <#=code.Escape(container)#> : DbContext
{
    public <#=code.Escape(container)#>()
        : base("name=<#=container.Name#>")
    {
<#
```

In quotes where it says "name=<#=container.Name#>"

replace it with

```
<#=Accessibility.ForType(container)#> partial class <#=code.Escape(container)#> : DbContext
{
    public <#=code.Escape(container)#>()
        : base("metadata = res://*/fda.csdl|res://*/fda.ssdl|res://*/fda.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string='data source=MyServer;initial catalog=CitywideEmployees;persist security info=True;user id=MyUserID;password=MyPassword!;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework'")
    {
<#
```

save your tt file

Comment: Is there any resource link for using this code escape syntax?

Comment: The book Programming Entity Framework: Building Data Centric Apps with the ADO.NET ...By Julia Lerman is good.  You can research free articles.  What I know is how to put code in the tt file, and if you change your edmx file the content in the tt file, will show in the edmx.  If you delete and create a brand new edmx, I can write reflection code, that is called from global.asax on startup, that can check for specific code in the dbcontext parent file, and alert and not run without adding specific code to the tt and edmx.  This is hard to explain, but I can help further if you want me to.